# Why does docker build keep asking me for the time zone even after I set it?

Tags: docker, timezone, dockerfile

Why does creating a new docker image using the dockerfile below keep asking me to select the timezone? I have tried multiple variations of the `ENV TZ` command to no avail.

```
 => => # Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
 => => # questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
 => => # the time zones in which they are located.
 => => #   1. Africa   3. Antarctica  5. Arctic  7. Atlantic  9. Indian    11. US
 => => #   2. America  4. Australia   6. Asia    8. Europe    10. Pacific  12. Etc
 => => # Geographic area:
```

I asks this after the `apt-get install` is finished.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

ENV TZ Europe/London

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get upgrade -y \
 && apt-get -y install autoconf automake bison bzip2 cmake doxygen diffutils flex g++ gcc git gzip libarchive13 libcurl4 libelf1 libgpgme11 libssl1.1 libtool libusb-dev m4 make libncurses-dev patch pkg-config python3 readline-common subversion tar tcl texinfo unzip wget xz-utils
```

Thanks!